# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)

Tags: magento2, javascript, permissions

I'm trying to install a module and I'm getting the following error when I navigate to the page to load it. As you can see it is saying 403 error 
[image]

Everything I have seen says that it is a permissions issue however as you can see the permissions are set correctly
[image]
[image]
[image]

Where do I go from here? What do I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use cloudflare and they had security settings enabled that didn't allow anyone to run javascript code on my website